# Count triangularizations of convex polygons such that each triangle created by triangularizations have atleast one side as polygon side.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let    $n$  be  an  integer greater than four,  and let $P_1,P_2,\dots, P_n$ be   a   convex  $n$-sided    polygon.    Zach     wants  to  draw    $n-3$ diagonals    that    partition the region    enclosed    by  the polygon into    $n-2$ triangular   regions and that    may intersect   only    at   the    vertices    of  the polygon.    In  addition,   he  wants   each    triangular  region  to  have    at  least   one side that   is  also    a   side    of  the polygon.    In  how many    different ways  can Zach     do this?

Comment: Don't you think it's a little childish to repeat the character " Zach" instead of saying "I" ? After all, it's you who is finally interested ...

Comment: Thanks to point out

Comment: Help totally stumped by that question

Comment: Not able to count by catalan numbers as it will involve those triangulariztions also which will have triangles that have no side common to polygon

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate, see the comment by the OP. It is proven at the linked site that there are $n\cdot2^{n-5}$ admissible triangulations. A considerably simpler proof goes as follows:

There are exactly two triangles $\triangle_1$, $\triangle_{n-2}$ having two sides on $\partial P$, and the remaining $n-4$  triangles form an ordered chain in between them. The structure of this chain can be encoded as an $\{L, R\}$-word of length $n-4$, supplemented with $\triangle_1$ and $\triangle_{n-2}$ at the ends, whereby $L$ (resp., $R$) means that the corresponding triangle has its $\partial P$-side   to the left (resp., to the right) of the "virtual backbone" connecting $\triangle_1$ with $\triangle_{n-2}$.

An example: When $n=9$ then such  a codeword could look like $\ \triangle_1\,RRLRL\>\triangle_7$.

Given such a codeword the corresponding chain of triangles can be embedded in $n$ ways into $P$. Since reversing the orientation of the "backbone" and at the same time interchanging $L$ and $R$ leads to equal triangulations we have to divide the obtained total $n\cdot 2^{n-4}$ by $2$ in order to get the correct number of triangulations.